# Small coding project won't catch FormatException

Tags: c#

So I recently started my first coding course for C#. I am currently trying to write a short program that prints out Yay! as many times as I indicate. Now to prevent any format exceptions, I've tried to add a try and catch to it. But, for some reason this isn't working and I can't seem to figure out why. The code is below:

```
  Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"Yay!\": ");
  string entry = Console.ReadLine();
  var number = int.Parse (entry);
  bool print = true;
  while(print)
  {
    try
    {
      if(number <= 0)
      {
        print = false;
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Yay!");
        number -= 1;
      }
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("You must enter a whole number.");
    }
  }
```

Now to my knowledge, I have everything I need to make this work. Can anyone see where I went wrong with this?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Ehm... the error must be at int.parse and it's outside the try/catch...

Comment: @Gusman You should make this an answer

Comment: @Sascha Really? I don't like to add answers which doesn't add value to StackOverflow...

Comment: @Kelly You code sample does not work as `print` is `true` forever. Read and assigning to print should be within the loop.

Comment: int.TryParse() would be a better solution.

Comment: Hint: look at the stack trace for the exception, and note that it occurs *outside* the `try` block... so it isn't going to be caught by the `catch` block.

Comment: You are probably getting an error on int.Parse(entry) which will get an error if you don't enter an integer.

Comment: @Gusman I understand your concern, but the question either takes this answer or a complete working sample with correct structure, both not giving value to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

```
 var number = int.Parse (entry);
```

that should throw the exception, and since it's *beyond* `try {}` scope, the
exception has not been caught. Move the fragment into the scope:

```
  Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"Yay!\": ");
  string entry = Console.ReadLine();
  bool print = true; 

  try {      
    // int.Parse is within the try {} scope now
    var number = int.Parse (entry);

    while(print) {
      ...
    }
  }
  catch(FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine("You must enter a whole number.");
  }
```

Or convert `int.Parse` into `int.TryParse` and drop `try {...} catch {...}` at all (a better solution)

```
  Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"Yay!\": ");

  int number;

  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) {
    Console.WriteLine("You must enter a whole number.");

    return;
  }

  bool print = true;

  // There's no need in try {} catch {} now
  while(print) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Great, that did it, thanks so much, I've been working on this problem for about 2 hours and I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Kelly: you're welcome! Try to *avoid* exceptions, esp. when they do not mean *exceptional situations*: user input like `"bla-bla-bla"` can well be expected and should be taken into account — the very purpose of ` if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) `

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `int.Parse` inside your try-catch block.

Here's a revised version of your code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        bool print = true;
        while (print)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"Yay!\": ");
            string entry = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                var number = int.Parse(entry);

                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Yay!");
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must enter a whole number.");
            }
        }
    }
```